# Using WCF WebApi project produces JSON objects with incorrect property names

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, json

I'm using the [WCF Project on Codeplex](http://wcf.codeplex.com/) (also known as [WebAPI via Nuget](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/WebApi.All)). My simple service produces XML beautifully, but returns JSON where every property is named "item".

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "all")]
public IQueryable<myobject> GetAllUsers() {
    return (from myobject u in MyDatabase.MyObjects
           select u).AsQueryable();
}
```

Here's the generated JSON.

```
[
  {
    "item":null,
    "item":641412011,
    "item":null,
    "item":"en_US",
    "item":"-7",
    "item":true
  }
]
```

The return value is a public class POCO.

```
[Serializable]
public class MyObject {
    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "first_name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "last_name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Has anyone seen this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry. Some digging tipped me off that I was missing the `[DataContract]` attribute on my POCO class.

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class MyObject {
    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "first_name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "last_name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming that you're using preview 5 of webapi. You can actually remove all the attributes you have on the poco class. Check out the sample on codeplex http://goo.gl/vYbEN